# react-admin pagination not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-admin

Created a simple react-admin application that pulls from a custom rest api. First page is displayed (default 10 per page. Click the Next button and nothing happens (still sends page=1 to the api). Click a second time and the page advances to page 2 (page=2), as expected. Click the third time and goes back to page 1 (page=1).

Then, if you click a fourth time, it goes page 2, then click again, goes to page 3, then click again, goes back to page 1. It continues with this pattern, each round, getting one page further before going back to page.

I'm able to get the correct results when calling the custom API outside of the react-admin app. I created a custom dataProvider to communicate with the API and maybe there's a problem with the getList function, but I can definitely see the page number passed into this function and it lines up with the odd results (page 1, then 1, 2, 1, then 1, 2, 3, 1, etc. The custom API expects the following query string for pagination: ?limit=10&page=1&orderBy=id&orderDir=ASC

The original react-admin tutorial returns 10 records. When I set the page limit to 5, it does seem to work OK (advances to page 2 on the first click of Next), but without more records, it's hard to test it completely. But my guess is it would work, since it is most certainly a problem with my code or the API (although, as I said, the API works outside the react app).

Here's my getList function:

```
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
  if (!options.headers) {
    options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
  }
  const tokens = localStorage.getItem('tokens');
  const objToken = JSON.parse(tokens);

  options.user = {
    authenticated: true,
    token: `Bearer ${objToken.accessToken}`
  };
  return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};

export default {
  getList: (resource, params) => {
    const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
    const { field, order } = params.sort;
    const { q } = params.filter;

    // Pagination and sort
    let query = `limit=${perPage}&page=${page}&orderBy=${field}&orderDir=${order}`;
    // Filter?
    let useResource = '';
    let useFilter = '';

    if (q == null) {
      // No filter: Use <resource>/ url
      useResource = resource;
    } else {
      // Filter: Use append url with /find
      useResource = `${resource}/find`;
      useFilter = q;
      console.log('useFilter: ', useFilter)
      query += `&searchText=${useFilter}`;
    }

    const url = `${apiUrl}/${useResource}?${query}`;
    return httpClient(url)
      .then(({ json }) => ({
        data: json.results,
        total: json.totalRows,
      }));
  }, ...
```

Here's a screen shot of issue:

[image]

EDIT:
It looks like the correct query string is being sent but immediately after the first Next page click (page=2), page=1 is automatically sent again, returning to page one. This seems to be the case with subsequent Next clicks, as well. Thanks for helping out a newbie. But I just can't figure out why extra calls are being made returning to page 1.

Comment: Hi, this seems to be a React-admin problem:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/4658
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/4616

Comment: Yes, it sure does look like the same problem. Thanks for pointing it out. But I don't know if I can work around it by removing strict mode, as it suggests (just starting with react). Or, do I need to wait until the RA folks to fix it?

Comment: The problem is critical, I think they will fix it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in react-admin 3.4.3.

I updated using npm update and pagination works correctly.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have exactly behavor with react 4.x.x

**What i was expecting:**

Going to next page when cliking on next, with react-admin 3.19 this is how my application worked

**What happened instead:**

when you click on the next page, pagination resets to 1 !
also, it does not take into account the pagination that I define.

on chrome default perPage is 5, even when i set it 10.

chrome_pagination_issue

on firefox default perPage=10, but i have the same issue

firefox_pagination_issue

**Other information:**

```js
getList: (resource, params) => {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        console.log(params);
        const query = {
            ...fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter),
            _sort: field,
            _order: order,
            _start: (page - 1) * perPage,
            _end: page * perPage,
            _resource:resource
        };
        const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

        return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => {
            
            if (!json.hasOwnProperty('totalElements')) {
                throw new Error(
                  "The numberOfElements property must be must be present in the Json response"
                );
            }
            return {
                data: json.content,
                total: parseInt(json.totalElements,10)
            };
        });
    }
```

#4658

**Environment**

React-admin version: 4.0.1 , 4.0.2
React version:18
Strict mode disabled
Browser: chrome, firefox
My backend is spring boot rest api

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31780849)